# How shall I send an image file in body of Http POST request in along with other form data angular 5. Backend is using Intervention package in Laravel

Tags: php, angular, http, post, angular5

[This is the postman data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw6xp.png)

This is what I have tried to implement

```
    @ViewChild('imageUpload') elem: ElementRef;



fetchImage() : File{
    const Imagefiles = this.elem.nativeElement
    this.profileImagefile = Imagefiles.files[0];
    console.log("ProfileImage",this.profileImagefile)
    return this.ProfileImagefile;
}



addUser(createAgent: NgForm) {

const formData: FormData = new FormData(createAgent.value);
    formData.append("image", this.fetchImage(), this.fetchImage().name)
    console.log("formData",formData)

    console.log('formvalue', createProfile.value);
    this.httpService.createProfile(createProfile.value)
        .subscribe(....)
```

In httpService

```
    createProfile(data: any) {
    return this.httpClient.post('agent/', data) }
```

The backend is using php Laravel. It Throws error for the form data sentthrough the HTTP POST. 
Through Postman the data can be sent but not able to do it from the FrontEnd
What is the right way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by first getting the all ngForm data and appending it into the form data then append image file to the same form data. 
Used for-in loop to get ngForm data.

```
        addUser(createAgent: NgForm) {                                     
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        for( let val in createAgent.value  ){
            formData.append(val, createAgent.value[val])
            console.log(val, createAgent.value[val])
        }
        formData.append("image", this.fetchImage(), this.fetchImage().name);
        console.log("formData",formData)
    }
```

Then send this form data to backend

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
uploadFile(fileType: FileType, file: File): Observable<string> {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('name', file.name.substring(0, file.name.indexOf(".")));
    formData.append('extension', file.name.substring(file.name.indexOf(".") + 1, file.name.length));
    formData.append('fileType', fileType);
    return this.fileHttpHandler
        .uploadFile(formData)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => this.restErrorHandler.handleRestError(error));
}
```

fileHttpHandler.uploadFile() looks like this:

```
public uploadFile(formData: FormData): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(this.restApiUtilsService.getUrl(this.FILES_API_PATH) + "/save",
        formData, this.restApiUtilsService.getMultipartAuthHeaders());
}
```

In headers, you don't have to specify anything like multipart - it's done automatically. I pass authentication token there, that's why there is "getMultipartAuthHeaders". Just don't specify Content-Type in headers at all.

Comment: how to send other form data along with this?. Thaks

Comment: Just use formData for this - in my example I add additional metadata - name, extension, file type.